# Getting the JSON reponse from an API with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, response

I am just messing with APIs and now I'm trying to use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1) in my app.

I made a form to get the user's input and retrieve this data and create the URI just in the `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/directions', function() {
    $origin = Input::get('origin');
    $destination = Input::get('destination');

    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" . $origin . "&destination=" . $destination . "&sensor=false";
});
```

That URL's response is a JSON. But now, how am I supposed to store that response with Laravel? I have been looking at the Http namespace in Laravel and I didn't find a way. If it can't be done with Laravel, how can it be done with plain php?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
Route::get('/directions', function() {
    $origin = Input::get('origin');
    $destination = Input::get('destination');

    $url = urlencode ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" . $origin . "&destination=" . $destination . "&sensor=false");

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

    dd($json);
});
```

Comment: thanks, that gets closer to what I wanted. However, 1: doesn't laravel provide any way to do this? and 2, I'm getting a 400 Bad Request with some characters. I tried wrapping the result of `file_get_contents` with `utf8_encode` but it doesn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: also `dd` is not "pretty printing" for some reason

Comment: `dd` is just to dump the variable to show you it works. You can do whatever you want with the variable to print it how you want.

Comment: As for "doesn't laravel provide any way to do this" - this *is* the way you do it. The other option is to use a package like Guzzle and curl the request - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Finally - I have modified my answer to include `urlencode()` to make it work for the other chars

Comment: I tried `urlencode()` too but it does not work: `file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fdirections%2Fjson%3Forigin%3Dlos+angeles%26destination%3Dnew+york%26sensor%3Dfalse): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ` The only thing that works is replacing white spaces with `%20` but this seems like an odd solution (I have encountered this in the past with a webapp made with python).

Comment: Without `urlencode()` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this step...

set route...

```
Route::get('/json', [yourController::class, 'getJSON']);
```

and the method for get value as json format

```
public function getJSON(Request $request)
{

    $url = 'https://api******';

    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $newsData = json_decode($response);


    return response()->json($newsData);         

}
```

Comment: @JaredSmith pointing out the response->json() justifies it, also this is first result when searching for laravel json api so question’s age does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my package

https://github.com/joshhornby/Http

Hopefully makes it a little easier to call APIs

Comment: I'll give it a look, looks good. I hope Laravel implements such thing.

Comment: "Take a look at my package" did you do that on purpose or was it inadvertent?